# GFCI Installed right, but no power when load is plugged in

Tags: gfci, load

As stated in the title, the GFCI works when it's just the line hooked up. However when I hook up the load wires, the outlet won't reset and nothing downstream works. Nothing I google helps me.

Comment: Then don't connect the load wires.  I mean, there's no question here.  Either repair the load or leave it disconnected.

Comment: You title says "plugged in" but your body says "hook up the load wires" Please [edit] to consistently state under what conditions the problem actually occurs.

Comment: [Edit] more details into the question (like pics of the wiring at the GFCI), and it will likely get reopened, however, Ecnerwal's answer is still 99.99999% guaranteed to be the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

So, it works with the line (including if you plug something into it, presumably, though you're not entirely explicit about that case.)

It does not work with the load wires connected, and trips/won't reset.

QED - there's a ground fault in/on the load wiring. Find and fix that.

When a GFCI trips or won't reset, the very **first** thought you should have is "it's working correctly and doing its job by detecting a ground fault" and *all other causes* are way, way down the odds. So look to that **first**.

Unplug every device on the load side. If that doesn't work, disconnect roughly halfway on the load side. Then halfway of what's left. Isolate where the problem originates, and look for the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you did everything right, then nothing can be improved, and there must be no problem with the GFCI receptacle.

Perhaps you need to revisit that it's installed right.  Wiring is not always easy, as the wires themselves may be mislabled, misidentified, damaged, or installed wrong.  Odds are much better that there is an error in your installation that you didn't consider, and the GFCI is functioning correctly (and possibly saving you a fire).

In the rare event that you are 100% certain it is right, and you are additionally 100% certain that you are right and not mistaken in that belief, then you might need to purchase a new GFCI.  That said, it's very rare that they are faulty out-of-the-box.

Comment: And even rarer that they are faulty out of the box (or later in life) but only on the load terminals. They generally either fail, period, or work as designed.

Answer (score 0):

A picture of how you wired the outlet would be helpful, pointing at power wires. GFCI's match input and output current within the device. If currents don't match, the gfi trips both the hot and neutral. The input wires and the output wires need to go to the right screws, and there can be no touching of neutral to ground anywhere down the line from the gfci (that would make an alternate path, bypassing gfci, so it would trip). Shared neutrals with other circuits would be a problem also, since that would provide an alternate path back as well.